# Is there a way to bypass the laravel unique validation string length check?

Tags: php, validation, unique, rules, laravel-6

While using the laravel built-in "unique" validation, the "length must greater than 3" keeps coming up. Is there a way to bypass or overwride? 
My validation is like: `'code' => 'required|unique:country,code',`
Will pass the 1st validation(required) and hang on the unique part for my term is only 2 characters like "TW" or "US". 
Thank you for your help.

Comment: unique validation doesn't require value to be of length 3 minimum!
it simply checks in database in specified column.
something else is wrong.
please add more code to your question.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible that unique makes that. You should verify your action to make sure validation rules you expect are used. Unique does not add any length constraints itself. You probably use somewhere in your code `min:3` rule that verified your code length.